# SQL query to detect Last Replication date time on publisher on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, sql-server-2012

I would like to know how to get the last Replication date/time by Query from the publisher on SQL Server 2012.

Please note I do not have access to the subscriber database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the `sysmergesubscriptions` table?

> Contains one row for each known Subscriber and is a local table at the
>   Publisher. This table is stored in the publication and subscription
>   databases.

It contains a column called `last_sync_date`:

last_sync_date - datetime - The datetime of the synchronization.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182728.aspx)